# Form is not getting validated using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a add button in upper right corner (see 1st screenshot) when I click on it, it displays form which has 3 input fields for adding name, contact number, group name and at last submit button.

I have added `required` attribute in `input` field of form but it does not work when I click on submit button it submits blank details (see 2nd screenshot)

in app.js:

I am dynamically adding HTML using javascript:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="addNewContact">
     <form>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="number">Number:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numberInput">
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="group">Group:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupInput">
      </div> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submitToDb()">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Screnshot:

[image]

Blank fields are displayed see screenshot:

[image]

Comment: change your type to button and not submit, you bind an onclick to an element that submits the entire form and does not trigger your javascript.

Comment: @Programmer I am trying this example https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_html

Comment: @Programmer If the browser doesn't know it's submitting, why will it perform the `required` checks?

Comment: @Barmar I am trying this example https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_html

Comment: Are you certain that your input values are empty? What happens if you remove the value attributes in your html?

Comment: @stonerock I would remove all javascript from your button and keep it as type submit.  Unobtrusive validation is the key word to learn from in this example. Your code should appear like this - <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: @Programmer I cannot remove JS from button as it saves the contact details in localstorage.

Comment: @Programmer I have edited my question please see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `onclick`, use `onsubmit` on the form.

```
<form onsubmit="submitToDb()">
```

Form validation is done when processing the `submit` event. If you use a button click to submit the form, that happens before the default submission occurs.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only difference is the name of the function.

Comment: I changed `onclick()` to `onsubmit()` and now it works like a charm. If you liked my question please do upvote it. Thank you :)

Comment: I `onsubmit()` is not working ? when I click it on submit it does not submits it onclick it just becomes static why so ?

Comment: You don't have `required` in the jsfiddle.

Comment: when I click on submit button with `onclick()` it atleast displays blank fields but with `onsubmit()` it does nothing ?

Comment: So I should also add `required` in input field ?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point if this question, about how to get input validation?

Comment: if you can mention in your answer also use `required` in `input` because I initially removed `required` and then changed `onclick()` to `onsubmit()`

Comment: You need to change your fiddle to use `No Wrap` so that you can call the functions from `onclick` and `onsubmit`.

Comment: I could not get you what is `No Wrap` ?

Comment: I have made the necessary changes in the code see screenhot -> https://imgur.com/a/YfZVJ  So sometimes my web app works fine but sometimes when I click on submit button it does not do anything why is this happening ?

Comment: How should I know? You've probably done something wrong, and the debugger will help you figure it out.

Comment: Finally fixed it :)